# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')

Tags: javascript, foreach, null, typeerror

I m getting uncaught typeError forEach is getting null values in my calculator so nothing is coming ion calci screen ..

```
(function(){
    let screen= document.querySelector(".screen");
    let buttons= document.querySelector(".btn");
    let clear= document.querySelector(".btn-clear");
    let green= document.querySelector(".btn-green");


    buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            let value = e.target.dataset.num;
            screen.value+= value;
        })
        
    });

})();
```

Comment: querySelectorAll, because querySelector return first element

Comment: This has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5DUncaught+TypeError%3A+Cannot+read+properties+of+null) more than two thousand times, please make a search before asking.

Comment: post your HTML code to understand your issue

Answer (score 0):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns `null` if there is no matched element. If you're iterate over found elements, use this snippet:

```js
let buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll(".btn")];
```

This snippet uses [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which converts [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) value to an array.